# The kernel lags when creating a large create_distplot by plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, data-visualization

I have an array of 250,000 elements. I want to plot a [`create_distplot`](https://plotly.com/python/distplot/).
It ends up plotting, but it is impossible to work further with the kernel, everything slows down and hangs. What can be the problem? I understand that size of data is very large, but how can I solve this problem?

```
x = np.fromfile("./data.txt", dtype="int64")
hist_data = [x]
group_labels = ['distplot'] # name of the dataset

fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels)
fig.show()
```

[image]

I attach the array in [the file](https://dropfiles.ru/download/32e8010dd339fc3232aa132c963fd25b.html)

P.S. If the file is deleted, the data can be generated as the tutorial:

```
x = np.random.randn(25000)
```